# Calculating percent difference between elements in a list with functional programming in Mathematica?

Tags: list, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

This stems from a related discussion, [How to subtract specific elements in a list using functional programming in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106501/how-to-subtract-specific-elements-in-a-list-using-functional-programming-in-mathe)

How does one go about easily calculating percent differences between values in a list?

The linked question uses Differences to easily calculate absolute differences between successive elements in a list. However easy the built-in Differences function makes that particular problem, it still leaves the question as to how to perform different manipulations.

As I mentioned earlier, I am looking to now calculate percent differences. Given a list of elements, `{value1, value2, ..., valueN}`, how does one perform an operation like `(value2-value1)/value1` to said list?

I've tried finding a way to use `Slot` or `SlotSequence` to isolate specific elements and then apply a custom function to them. Is this the most efficient way to do something like this (assuming that there is a way to isolate elements and perform operations on them)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few natural ways to do it.

You could form the list of arguments to your "percentage decrease" function using [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html):

```
In[3]:= list = {a, b, c, d, e};

In[4]:= Partition[list, 2, 1]

Out[4]= {{a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {d, e}}
```

Then you can [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) a function to these:

```
In[6]:= f @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]

Out[6]= {f[a, b], f[b, c], f[c, d], f[d, e]}
```

Using your percent decrease function:

```
In[7]:= PercentDecrease[a_, b_] := (b - a)/a

In[8]:= PercentDecrease @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]

Out[8]= {(-a + b)/a, (-b + c)/b, (-c + d)/c, (-d + e)/d}
```

(Read about @@@ by looking at the "More Information" notes at [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).)

Instead of Partition you can use [Most](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Most.html) and [Rest](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rest.html) to form lists of the first and second arguments and then combine them using [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html):

```
In[14]:= MapThread[PercentDecrease, {Most[list], Rest[list]}]

Out[14]= {(-a + b)/a, (-b + c)/b, (-c + d)/c, (-d + e)/d}
```

A different way is to form your operation (a subtraction and a division) in two steps like this:

```
In[10]:= Differences[list] / Most[list]

Out[10]= {(-a + b)/a, (-b + c)/b, (-c + d)/c, (-d + e)/d}
```

The divide operation (/) [threads](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) over the two lists `Differences[list]` and `Most[list`].

Comment: Great answer!  By the way, I like this explanation of @@@ better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141166/in-mathematica-what-does-mean/1141701#1141701

Comment: +1, great answer.  I personally, like the last one the best.  Although, I'd probably write it `Differences[#]/Most[#]& @ list`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Map.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/MapAFunctionOverAList.html

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = {e, d, c, b, a};  (* ordered for display convenience *)
Ratios[lst] - 1   (* the answer *)
Together /@ %  (* just for display *)
```